# How to find the probability current density of hydrogen atom wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, probability, quantum-interpretations, hydrogen

Can someone give me a book recommendation or a pdf where I can find how to get the radial, polar and azimuth component of it? I try to do it myself but I can't really figure out what to do next,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the [wavefunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction)? Then you can take some derivatives to find the [probability current density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current#Definition_(non-relativistic_3-current)) in three dimensions. It is probably easiest to use the gradient operator expressed in [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). The steps are for you to do, but these should take you directly to the answer!